# Azure Index Error: A resource without a type name was found, but no expected type was specified. What does it mean?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cognitive-services

I recently started receiving this error message after having dropped an index to recreate it. The index definition is identical to the one that was dropped so I don't understand the meaning of the error.

The full error is:

```
{"error":{"code":"","message":"The request is invalid. Details: indexer : A resource without a type name was found, but no expected type was specified. To allow entries without type information, the expected type must also be specified when the model is specified.\r\n"}}
```

What exactly is the "Resource without a type name" that was found when I've clearly dropped the index? And more importantly, how do I fix the problem???

Every field in the definition has a name and type specified.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED: The error is very convoluted and misleading. The problem was in the Uri I was using.

It was https://company-development.search.windows.net/indexers?api-version=2019-05-06

When it should have been https://company-development.search.windows.net/indexes?api-version=2019-05-06

I'm not certain whether the Url posted in our company Wiki contained a typo or if the Url may have been valid at some prior point but using the correct Url resolved the problem.